# TYPO3 extension: multiple input forms for a property

Tags: typo3

I'm developing a TYPO3 extension (backend usage only). There is a special property of a class I want the user to have multiple input forms for and the input forms should all be added to an array if the record for this model is saved. It should be like the "create multiple pages" form in the TYPO3 backend when you click on "Functions". So there should be also some "add new lines" button to theoretically add infinite input forms (and therefore multiple strings to the array).

Comment: Have you checked [IRRE](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html) ([Wiki](https://wiki.typo3.org/Inline_Relational_Record_Editing#Functionality_of_Inline_Relational_Record_Editing))? May be what you want... think of images in content elements in newer versions.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: Do you use TCA for editing or do you have a backend module ?

Comment: I use the TCA for this.